# What transformation describes how the fish sees the world above the water?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

What transformation (mapping) describes how the fish (or a diver) sees the world above the water?

There will be a region constrained by the total internal reflection but inside the cone what causes the bending?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The bending is caused by a change in refractive index.  The change in refractive index relates to the idea that light travels slower in water.